get lines from a ifstream into strings in a range-based for loop
I use to parse lines from a file by writing,
ifstream input(filename);
for (string line; getline(input, line); /**/)
  do_something_with(line);
...

but is it possible to elegantly (or with some boost magic) convert it into a more terse form with range-based for loop, i.e. does something like getline_range in an example below exist?
for (const auto& line : getline_range(ifstream(filename)))
  do_something_with(line);
...


I personally find std::string line; while (std::getline(file, line))  { ... } terse enough.

tersness is not a goal in C++. The compiler will usually still generate the same code anyway. So don't try to outsmart yourself and allow yourself to write that extra line every now and then.

@wohlstad that leaks line into the enclosing scope

@Caleth you can always enclose it into a local scope with {}, but to be honest the question didn't contain any info that indicates having the line variable in the enclosing scope is causing any problem.

There isn't anything in std like this, and I don't know of anything in boost either, but it's not hard to write with C++23's std::generator
std::generator<std::string> getlines(std::istream&& stream) {
    for (std::string line; getline(stream, line); ) co_yield line;
}


Excellent! Nevertheless, for those without C++23, what about something like for (auto& string : input | split('\n')) ... ?

@DarkoVeberic you'd have to write that split yourself

FWIW, I find using a while loop in this case more readable than a for loop.
It's also quite terse (although as noted above tersness should not be a primary goal when writing C++):
std::string line; 
while (std::getline(file, line))  
    do_something_with(line);

If you have a good reason not to have the line variable affect the enclosing scope, you can enclose these few lines with { ... } to create a local scope.
